# PHP Error, syntax error T_STRING!

Tags: php, parsing

I get the following error;

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\site\register.php on line 95
```

Line 95 is;

```
if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") strlen($email) >=6))
```

Please help, I don't know what's wrong :/ It all looks fine to me.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced for one.

Comment: have you considered using an IDE, it will highlight syntax errors and help balance your parentheses

Answer (score 4):

You forgot an operator before your `strlen()` call. Also, you have an extra `)` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error occurs at this position:

```
if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") strlen($email) >=6))
                                               ^
```

Furthermore you have one closing parenthesis but no corresponding opening parenthesis:

```
if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") strlen($email) >=6))
                                                                  ^
```

What you probably meant:

```
if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") && strlen($email) >= 6)
```

Or:

```
if (strstr($email, "@") && strstr($email, ".") && (strlen($email) >= 6))
```

Comment: Well, it fixed that.. But now I get another new error :/

unexpected T_ELSE on line 102

I'll try and figure that one out myself, thanks though! :)